# Override alphabetical default ORDER BY with a UNION of 2+ tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Really quick question... I have 4 tables that are `UNION`-ed together like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table1  
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2  
UNION
SELECT * FROM table3  
UNION
SELECT * FROM table4
```

Without specifying an `ORDER BY`, the query orders by the first column in ascending alphabetical order (which in my case happens to be a `varchar` type). I don't want `ORDER BY [Column1] DESC` either.

I simply want to order the results in the same order as the tables themselves are `UNION`-ed. 1, 2, 3, 4.

Is there a simply way to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way

```
SELECT *,1 as SortOrder FROM table1  
UNION
SELECT *,2 FROM table2  
UNION
SELECT *,3 FROM table3  
UNION
SELECT *,4 FROM table4
order by SortOrder
```

what happens is that you are using UNION, sql server then makes the result set distinct, in order to do that it needs to sort the tables

Does `UNION ALL` make a difference?

Comment: YES! Using `UNION ALL` does the trick. Can somebody confirm that this is normal?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no guarantee that a `UNION ALL` _must_ behave this way. I suspect that even with `ALL` SQLMenace's trick is required.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue. We have a union query with 32 subsets. We use it to populate a spreadsheet that is then used to build a PowerPoint presentation. The first field in each query is a text field that is a description of the data point. The spreadsheet is expecting the data to be in a specific order.

We made a slight change to one of the fields:

```
Concat('Annual incidence rate- ', Year(start_date))
```

This caused SQL to sort the unions in alphabetical order! I suspect that if you ordered your query as @SQLMenace indicated, but with a slight modification, it would work too.

```
SELECT '1', * FROM table1  
UNION
SELECT '2', * FROM table2  
UNION
SELECT '3', * FROM table3  
UNION
SELECT '4', * FROM table4
```

This might alleviate the outer query wrapper. It might work without the quotes, too.