# Can I INSERT a row at index n of a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, insert, union

I know I can do a `UNION` - but is there a better way to do this? We are using dynamic `SQL` and have it stored in tables with some the statements having an `ORDER BY` clause. I have to add a dynamic 'All' option, which is also stored in the database, to the top position to fill a drop-down in the app layer.

I know this is a wonky solution, but I'm trapped by the application's current design. The other option is adding a bunch of code to the data model and app layer in addition to changing the stored procedure. If `UNION` is my only/best option, I can do that. I was just wondering if there was a better way *on the database side*.

Also, I don't want a discussion on the merit of dynamic `SQL` strings stored in a database. It's the way it is and it's what I have to work with. Thanks all!

Comment: In a SQL database, there is no *pre-defined* order, e.g. you cannot insert a row at "position 42" - there is no such thing. The order is only defined when you **select** the data and explicitly specify a `ORDER BY` clause. If you need to enforce an ordering, you can add e.g. a `sequence` (int) column and fill it with the appropriate values, so that you can do a `SELECT (list-of-cols) FROM dbo.YourTable ORDER BY sequence` and get back the data in the sequence you want / need.

Comment: Had a feeling that was coming. Was just hoping there was a way.

Comment: Can you use a `NULL` value to represent "All"?  It will sort before any other values or the `ORDER BY` can be tweaked using a `CASE` to put it at the other end of the sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your existing ORDER BY column(s) do not fulfil your current needs. Why don't you add another column which explicitly details the Drop-Down control item placement, then ORDER BY that column in your Stored Procedure?

I'll spare you the lecture on dynamic SQL. Just be careful with user input eh? ;)

Comment: Injection isn't a problem with how we're doing it. We provide the options, so unless we inject our own database, we're fine. I'll keep an eye out for drop-down items that show "DROP TABLE USERS;" =)

Comment: The problem with the ORDER BY is that it's also coded into the stored SQL strings. Those strings are executed, which gives me the results I have to add to. I'm going to give UNION a shot and see what happens. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Yatrix - that does sound tricky. Is this other StackOverflow question relevant, or is it what you were referring to in your original query? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903149/override-alphabetical-default-order-by-with-a-union-of-2-tables